# Can ping other machine on LAN by IP number but not by name

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, router, dns, ping

Suddenly my Win 7 machine is unable to ping by name an XP machine on the LAN, but by IP number it works.

What could be the problem?

The Win 7 machine is connected to the router wirelessly, but the XP machine is connected by cable to the router.

Comment: Need more info: how does it know the name in the first place?  Does your machine have an entry in the hosts file, or does the router have DNS for the LAN?

Comment: When I ping the Win 7 machine name from itself I get: `Reply from fe80::1004:a8b0:9e40:a42c%10: time<1ms
Reply from fe80::1004:a8b0:9e40:a42c%10: time<1ms` instead of a normal IP address. What does that mean?

Comment: That's IPv6.  If you look at your Network Adapter, you'll see IPv6 turned on.  That has nothing to do with the name.

Comment: But when I ping other machines I get a normal (IPv4?) address. Why aren't I getting a normal IP address for my own machine?

Comment: Your question says that you are unable to ping them by name, and your comment says you are able to ping them by name, using IPv6.  If your question is regarding IPv4 versus IPv6 then please [edit] your question and make sure it reflects that.

Comment: @Paul: see new question here http://superuser.com/q/419581/39091

Comment: CraigJ, there is no need to open a new question when you can just edit this one to reflect the new information.  It just clutters the system.  What do you want to do with this one?  Please request a mod to delete it if it serves no purpose.

Comment: @Paul: the current question stands and I would like an answer to it. Perhaps the answer relates to NetBIOS. This has nothing to do with the second question I have created. I think they both deserve separate answers.

Comment: @Paul: There's no need to contact a mod, there are no answers yet so he can just delete his own question if he wants to. Only when there's an answer, you need to vote to delete it or contact mod.

Comment: @CraigJ Ok cool, can you check that both the W7 machine and the XP machine are in the same workgroup?

Comment: @Paul: you are right, I encountered this same problem on another network and the problem was solved by ensuring they are on the same workgroup. Does the workgroup have an effect on NetBIOS?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  Pinging using netbios name will only work within the same workgroup/domain (in the absense of proper dns setup)

Comment: @Paul: when you say 'proper DNS setup' are you referring to the router or the Windows machines?

Comment: No I mean a DNS server that can resolve names from different domains or workgroups - don't worry, this isn't common in a home environment, you don't really need it if you keep your workgroups straight.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem and I offer the following in case it might help people with the same issue:

First I went into the WINS tab inside the TP/TCP settings of the LAN connection and enabled NetBIOS.

Then I did `ipconfig /flushdns` from the command prompt.

I then changed the NetBIOS setting back to default in the WINS tab.

The problem has gone away now, but I don't know exactly what had fixed it.

EDIT: Another thing that can fix this issue is making sure both machines are on the same Workgroup.